# IF there is no result on search bar read "no results"

Tags: php, mysql, resultset, searchbar

I'm trying to make a filter search bar, and it works, but the "no results" page isn't. I've tried making the "no results" show up, but whatever I do, it doesn't.(php/mysql) Thanks so much for the help! Here's my code:

```
                <?php

                if(isset($_GET['search'])){

                  $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];

                  $run_query_by_pro_id = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products WHERE product_keywords like '%$search_query%'");


                  while($row_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_by_pro_id)){

                      $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];

                      $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
                      $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
                      $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
                      $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
               $pro_price_old = $row_pro['product-old-price'];



                  echo "
             

<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
    


  
<a href='product.php?p=$pro_id'>

<div class='row1'>
     <div class='col4'>

     <img  src='product_images/$pro_image' alt=''></a>
        <a href='product.php?p=$pro_id'>$pro_title</a>
        <div class='rating' >
            <i class='fa fa-star'></i>
            <i class='fa fa-star'></i>
            <i class='fa fa-star'></i>
            <i class='fa fa-star'></i>
            <i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>

        </div>
        <p>From <del class='product-old-price'>$$pro_price_old</del> to $$pro_price
        </p>
  <center>
     <div class='product-btns'>
                                        <button class='add-to-wishlist' ><i class='fa fa-heart-o'></i><span class='tooltipp'>add to wishlist</span></button>
                                        <button class='add-to-compare'><i class='fa fa-exchange'></i><span class='tooltipp'>add to compare</span></button>
                                        <button class='quick-view' ><i class='fa fa-eye'></i><span class='tooltipp'>quick view</span></button>
                                    
  </center>

                                
                                <div class='add-to-cart'>
                                    <button pid='$pro_id' id='product' href='#' tabindex='0' class='add-to-cart-btn'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> add to cart</button>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
</div>

    
    
    
    
    
                   
        ";
                  }

                }
                ?>
```

Comment: A message saying that there is too little text in your question compared to the amount of code you have shown, does _not_ mean that you should simply copy&paste the same text into the question multiple times over ...

Comment: Just check how many records the result contains, if it is zero, output your message, else let the while loop output the records. https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: And btw., this is currently wide open to SQL injection. You should go read up on the use of prepared statements as well.